# User is loggin outted when the config parameter changed?

Tags: php, yii

I have `name` parameter in my config main file:

```
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'Test Site',
```

but when I'm trying to change it the user is loggin outted, why?

```
//Yii::app()->name = 'Site';
var_dump(Yii::app()->user->isGuest); // bool(false)
...
Yii::app()->name = 'Site';
var_dump(Yii::app()->user->isGuest); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I research in YII code and get conclusion that YII use site name to create a unique id and this ID is append in his session variable.

see the code how it create id for session

```
$this->_id=sprintf('%x',crc32($this->getBasePath().$this->name));
```

you can trace cWebUser class. you will get this thing.

That's way this is happening in your code.